# What is the name of German-language horror or crime pulp novel series from late 80s/early 90s?

Tags: identification-request, short-stories, german-language

Back in the very early 90s, my father worked in Germany. The previous tenant in his apartment left some 80s/early-90s 7" vinyls, floppy discs and some horror/crime stich-bound short novels. Although the records and floppies are still around, the novels/magazines seem to be long lost (probably recycled into new magazines by now haha). However, I would still like to know what they were actually.

Some information:

- the "novels" were in a form of pulp magazine, probably 50 or so pages long and used either saddle stich binding (more likely) or so-called perfect binding (less likely) and the covers were soft
- they were written in German language (I don't know if the authors themselves were from German-speaking countries; I don't even know if there were one or more authors/stories per magazine)
- the covers featured scenes that were creepy for me as a kid (mostly murder scenes) and a lot of the covers were in yellow or orange colour
- the covers were artworks, not photos
- as almost everything that the tenant left was either from 80s or early 90s, I guess these magazines/novels were too

EDIT:
Forgot to mention, I looked upon some of the titles (crime and horror-related) listed [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_von_deutschsprachigen_Heftroman-Reihen,_-Serien_und_-Unterserien), but couldn't find it. I am quite aware that most of them don't have their covers scanned and posted online, so a good memory of some user is the only hope here. The yellow covers seem to be the only true distinction here.

Comment: This seems like it's unlikely to get a good answer in that this is basically "list pulp magazines published over about a decade in Germany" without more details. I'm guessing they're probably crime stories, based on your comment about murder scenes, but I'm not sure if that narrows it down much.

Comment: I have actually looked upon "list of pulp magazines" about crime released durign that time, but none seems to fit. Yellow covers are really a sign of distinction here, and nothing more besides that :(